# Learning with Codecademy, cant figure this error out

Tags: c#

im learning to code with Codecademy and i cant figure this one out. it says "Biome should accept Tropical as a value". It doesnt give me a syntax error tho. Thanks for the help in advance!

//The actual question/instruction of Codecademy!

"Define a Biome property for the biome field. It will have a getter and setter. The setter should only allow three values: "Tropical", "Temperate", and "Boreal". If any other value is used, set biome to "Unknown".

```
         //THIS IS THE FOREST CLASS!
    {
              class Forest
              {
                public string name;
                public int trees;
                public int age;
                public string biome;
                
                public string Name
                {
                  get {return name;}
                  set
                  {
                   name = Name;
                  }
                }
                 public int Trees
                 {
                    get {return trees;}
                    set
                    {
                      trees = Trees;
            
                    }
            
                 }
            
                 public string Biome{
                   get {return biome;}
                   set {
                     if (Biome == "Temperate" ||
                         Biome == "Tropical" ||
                         Biome == "Boreal"){
                           biome = Biome;
                         }
                      else 
                      {
                        biome = null;
                      }
            
                       }
                   }
            
            
                
              }


   //THIS IS THE PROGRAM CLASS!

     using System;
    
    namespace BasicClasses
    {
      class Program
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Forest f = new Forest();
          f.Name = "Congo";
          f.Trees = 0;
          f.age = 0;
          f.Biome = "Tropical";
          
          Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
          Console.WriteLine(f.Biome);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: does biome need to be a string?  have you considered an enumerator?

Comment: Setter shoud not reference back to itself. Setters receives an argument called value and you should use it to do your operations inside the setter code

Comment: _"If any other value is used, set biome to `"Unknown"`"_ Remember that `"Unknown" != null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Property setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) receives an argument called value and you should use it to update your internal fields and, these internal fields (called backing fields for properties) should not be public otherwise any logic that you put in the setter/getter code could be bypassed accessing directly these fields

```
class Forest
{
    // Internal fields should be private
    private string name;
    private int trees;
    private int age;
    private string biome;

    public string Name
    {
         get {return name;}
         set {name = value;}
    }
    public int Trees
    {
        get {return trees;}
        set {trees = value};
    }

    public string Biome
    {
        get {return biome;}
        set 
        {
            if (value == "Temperate" ||
                value == "Tropical" ||
                value == "Boreal")
            {
                biome = value;
            }
            else 
            {
               biome = "Unknow";
            }
       }
   }
```

However I agree with the comment above that your Biome should be a property of type BiomeEnum so the compiler helps you to avoid setting it to an invalid value

```
   public enum BiomeEnum
   {
        Unknow = 0,
        Temperate = 1,
        Tropical = 2,
        Boreal = 3
   }

   ...
   public BiomeEnum Biome
   {
        get {return biome;}
        set { biome = value;}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! you both helped out :)

Comment: this is all kinda new to me but i kinda can see where enum is good for. nice one to know about!

Answer (score 1):

Use `value` inside the setter

```
public string Biome {
  get {
    return biome;
  }
  set {
    if (value == "Temperate" ||
      value == "Tropical" ||
      value == "Boreal") {
      biome = value;
    } else {
      biome = "Unknown";
    }
  }
}
```